# Prevent Editable Div from Vertical Stretch and Overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, contenteditable

I am using a Content Editable Div, and I want to prevent the div from vertical stretching so that the cursor cannot go passed the fixed height.

I do not want to hide the overflow, I want to prevent the overflow.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/yaq7a/

```
.cke_editable {
border:2px solid #777;
max-height: 300px;
height: 300px;
width: 400px;
}
```

I am hoping there is a way to stop the cursor when it reaches the bottom of the editable div so that it would not be possible to add lines beyond the fixed height of the div.

I am using HTML5 and JQ if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change `max-height` to `min-height`

```
.cke_editable {
    border:2px solid #777;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

[Demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/yaq7a/3/)

Comment: I don't want the top div to stretch beyond the 300px. In your demo, the height of the div is 387px. I need it to stop at 300px so that it is not possible to type beyond that point. The layout must remain fixed without any stretching or overflow.